# Reading 3 characters in a line until a specific character is typed

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use `scanf` to read 3 inputs in a line until it encounters a character `'E'` in a newline. Why it doesn't stop scanning until I type in an another character after the character `'E'`?

```
char s[200];

char ch='A';
int ind=0;

while(ch!='E')
{
    scanf("%c ",&ch);
    s[ind]=ch;
    ind=ind+1;

}
printf("%c",s[2]);
```

[My result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSS6h.png)

Comment: `fgetc` or `getc` might be more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a *trailing* space in the `scanf` format string.

That will lead `scanf` to read and ignore all white-space (spaces, tab, newlines) until it reaches a non-space character.

One simple solution is to use *leading* space in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
//     ^
// Note leading space
```

I haven't added any error checking, but you should really check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). I also recommend you add it as a part of the loop condition itself:

```
char ch;

while (scanf(" %c", &ch) == 1 && ch != 'E')
{
    // Use ch
}
```

---

Another possible solution is to use a character-reading function like [`fgetc` or `getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) or [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). But do note that these return an **`int`** which is important because you also need to remember to check the character returned against `EOF`:

```
int ch;  // Need to be an int for the EOF check to work

while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != 'E')
{
    if (isspace(ch))
        continue;  // Don't bother with any kind of space

    // Use ch
}
```

While using `getc` as shown above might seem to be more work, it's also more flexible and give you greater control over how to handle different character and character classes.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk It tells `scanf` to read zero or more white-space (any space) and one character. It's missing error checking (checking that `scanf` [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) `1`), but other than that it should work almost the same as the OPs current solution (but without the need for typing an extra character).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Solution 1 works for me. However, for solution 2, I need to add like the following code to skip whites paces and new line. 
if((ch!=' ')&&(ch!='\n'))
        {
            s[ind] = ch;
            ind = ind + 1;
        }

Comment: @HarveyYeh Using `isspace` is better, updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getc` or `fgetc` for better answer. Here I am pasting a working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char s[200];

  char ch = 'A';
  int ind = 0;

  while (ch != 'E')
    {
      ch = getc(stdin); //Instead of scanf you can use getc
      s[ind] = ch;
      ind = ind + 1;

    }
  printf ("%c", s[2]);
  return 0;
}
```